# MathNet Numerics Complex32 ToString Method returning incorrect format

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I tried to use the `ToString()` method to convert a `Complex32` value in the form: `Z = x + iy`.

There are these overloads of the `ToString()` Method: [Complex32 ToString Overloads](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Complex32.htm#ToString):

```
string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
string ToString(string format)
string ToString() // returns result (0,0)B for number: Z=0+i0
```

- How do I use the other overloads?
- How can I recieve `0+i0` instead of `(0,0)B` from `ToString()`?
- Or is it impossible and I need to create the string manually?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parameters to use the other methods

like

`num.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));`